# Load all html in directory using iframe

Tags: javascript, html

I know it is possible to load the content of an html document in another html document (call it "master.html") using iframe; i.e.:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Sample code</h1>
        <p>Sample code</p>

        <iframe src="files\file_1.html" 
            name="targetframe" 
            allowTransparency="false" 
            height = 500
            width = 1200
            frameborder="0" >
        </iframe>

    </body>
</html>
```

In this case, I loaded "file_1.html" from the directory "files."  Let's say I have 100 .html documents in "files," all with differing names (i.e., "file_1.html," "something_else.html", "something_random.html").

Is there a way that I can load all the .html documents contained in "files" consecutively into "master.html?"

Thanks so much for your responses!

Comment: Javascript does not allow permissions to read from a server directory. Therefore you would need server-side code to dynamically produce the list of available files in the directory. Are you using a server-side language?

Comment: I'm new to this, so the above code is all I have knowledge of.

Comment: Do the file names you wish to include follow a pattern?  You can still use JS, but it won't scan the folder for filenames.